# number as consecutive bits

Tags: numbers, bit

What would be the fastest way to represent a number as a set of consecutive bits?
Number range: 1-32, output to be stored in unsigned 32 bit variable.

input : 1

output: 10000000000000000000000000000000

input : 5

output: 11111000000000000000000000000000

input : 16

output: 11111111111111110000000000000000

input : 31

output: 11111111111111111111111111111110

I am using C language, but if you can give a faster example in assembly it is welcome.

My current code is this:

```
uint get_bitmap_left(uint num) {

    if (num== 1) return(0x80000000);
    if (num== 2) return(0xC0000000);
    if (num== 3) return(0xE0000000);
    if (num== 4) return(0xF0000000);
    if (num== 5) return(0xF8000000);
    if (num== 6) return(0xFC000000);
    if (num== 7) return(0xFE000000);
    if (num== 8) return(0xFF000000);
    if (num== 9) return(0xFF800000);
    if (num==10) return(0xFFC00000);
    if (num==11) return(0xFFE00000);
    if (num==12) return(0xFFF00000);
    if (num==13) return(0xFFF80000);
    if (num==14) return(0xFFFC0000);
    if (num==15) return(0xFFFE0000);
    if (num==16) return(0xFFFF0000);
    if (num==17) return(0xFFFF8000);
    if (num==18) return(0xFFFFC000);
    if (num==19) return(0xFFFFE000);
    if (num==20) return(0xFFFFF000);
    if (num==21) return(0xFFFFF800);
    if (num==22) return(0xFFFFFC00);
    if (num==23) return(0xFFFFFE00);
    if (num==24) return(0xFFFFFF00);
    if (num==25) return(0xFFFFFF80);
    if (num==26) return(0xFFFFFFC0);
    if (num==27) return(0xFFFFFFE0);
    if (num==28) return(0xFFFFFFF0);
    if (num==29) return(0xFFFFFFF8);
    if (num==30) return(0xFFFFFFFC);
    if (num==31) return(0xFFFFFFFE);
    if (num==32) return(0xFFFFFFFF);

    returrn(0);
}
```

Comment: Well, that can't be your code, unless you've created a `returrn()` function somewhere else.

Comment: Fastest? Least execution time? Least code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return 0xFFFFFFFF << (32 - num);`